# Wrong PHP Version/Executable in VSCode terminal but works perfectly in Mac terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpunit, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, php-8

I just updated my Mac M1 to Big Sur 11.5.2 and something in VSCode seems to have broken.
I am unable to use the latest home-brew php which is installed.

In VSCode its pointing to /usr/bin/php which is Macs built in php, that's not the one im using with home-brew. I tried everything and changed the path but still the same thing.

I checked the one similar question to mine and all it suggests is to use Homebrew which I already am doing so Im not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am running PHPUnit tests in the VSCode terminal and I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/map -> ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests                           
/usr/bin/php declares an invalid value for PHP_VERSION.
This breaks fundamental functionality such as version_compare().
Please use a different PHP interpreter.
/Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/map ->
```

However when I run the same thing in the Mac terminal by going to the same folder it works perfectly:

```
/Users/themyth/app/Sites/MapFramework/Map -> ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests                                            
PHPUnit 9.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.0.9
Configuration: /Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/Map/phpunit.xml

...R                                                                4 / 4 (100%)

Time: 00:00.004, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) tests\map\core\exception\MapExceptionTest::testDisplayMethodShowsBasicStaticHtml
This test did not perform any assertions

/Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/Map/tests/map/core/exception/MapExceptionTest.php:16

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 4, Risky: 1.
/Users/themyth/app/Sites/MapFramework/Map ->
```

When I do which php in both terminals I get a different result:

In Mac terminal:

```
/Users/themyth/app/Sites/MapFramework/Map -> which php
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

In VSCode terminal:

```
/Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/map -> which php
/usr/bin/php
/Users/themyth/App/Sites/MapFramework/map ->
```

How can I point VSCode to the right version of PHP? I don't think this happened before doing the Big Sur update and I am not sure what to edit.

I tried to open settings.json but I can't find any info about this and I am not sure how to edit this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

##### Edit 1:

I think this issue happened since I installed PHPIntellisense on VSCode but can't be sure, what I do know is that it was working before.
I dont know how to configure VSCode to point to the home-brew PHP which is already installed and working perfectly in the regular terminal

---

##### Edit 2

I tried to edit settings.json and it made no difference:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Dimmed",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php",
    "php.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php"
}
```

---

##### Edit 3

I have completely uninstalled VSCode and reinstalled everything. To start from fresh and the same problem happens.
This is what the current settings.json file looks like:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "php.validate.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php"
}
```

When I do which php in the terminal in VSCode I always get the same thing /usr/bin/php

The same problem is continuing, Im not sure if this is because of the OSX update.

How could I configure the VSCode terminal to be exactly like the Mac terminal?

I also opened another project where I am using Symfony and I am trying to create a basic controller & that doesn't work too.
I have edited the question to be more generic now:

php bin/console make:controller test
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS)
```

What is most frustrating is this seems so straight forward I can't understand what I need to do to fix this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same problem. Open your terminal and write this:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

At the top of the file you have this:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Put this line just under:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.0/bin:$PATH
```

Save and close, restart your terminal and it will normally work.

NB: I write php@8.0 but you can do this with all versions you install with homebrew

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. My only thing is I would have preferred the VSCode terminal to work properly out of the box. Why is it that it picks up everything else properly but not PHP? Just one other thing, your path is /opt/homebrew/opt/php. but in my Mac m1 its /opt/homebrew/bin/php  should I put my path or is there a reason for that?

Comment: Great! It works, but I just want to ensure this is the correct solution and something that will work later on as well, what if I have software updates, The VSCode terminal is still different from the Mac terminal when it comes to PHP

Comment: Only other issue with this is what if there is an update? What if I want to switch versions, this needs to constantly be updated. Is there not another way this can be fixed in a more permanent elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

It might be you are trying to use XDebug to run/debug your code. In that case despite doing the above, it still didn't work! I had to edit launch.json to add "runtimeExecutable" (which I did in both blocks) so it looks something like this (use brew --prefix php to find the right path to use):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 0,
        "runtimeArgs": [
          "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
        ],
        "runtimeExecutable": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php",
        "env": {
          "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
          "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
        }
      },
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "runtimeExecutable": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mamp, just check this checkbox
[image: Change php version in Mac when using Mamp]

[image]

if you are not using Mamp, check your .zshrc file in ~/ folder

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using XAMPP instead of Homebrew follow these 2 steps:
1.nano ~/.zshrc
2.export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin:$PATH

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked user settings, settings.json. Look for "php.executablePath": "c:\php80\php.exe",